Looking for a 70s film about time travel and dinosaurs
It was made in the 70s. It starts with a song played over the opening credits. Then a guy has a dinner with his girlfriend outdoors discussing his plans or something. A bit later, he and a few other people (who work for a company) time travel. When they're in the past, they see dinosaurs. At the end, he decides to stay in the past with his new cave woman girlfriend.

Welcome to Movies & TV! Please [edit] in any details you know: Country of origin (or at least language), actors you recognize (or even just what they look like), was it in theaters or only on TV, any other minor plot points.  The more you can give us, the more likely we can help you.

The Last Dinosaur, (1977).  The cavewoman girlfriend is named "Hazel".  The movie ends with the main character deciding not to leave with the rest of the expedition, but to stay in the warm polar subterranean valley, (NOT the past), to continue his war against the Tyrannosaurus Rex:

Frankie pleads with Thrust to go with them and to leave the dinosaur,
  as it is the "last one." Thrust replies "So am I..." and so they leave
  without him. Now it is just Thrust (and Hazel) in this primeval world
  with "The Last Dinosaur."

The memorable theme song and some clips from the movie are available on Youtube.
